# WPF: Label text does not stay centered in gridcell

Tags: c#, wpf, text, label, center

I have this simple window for the purpose of showing my problem:

```
<Window x:Class="BattleShip.Views.test"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="test" Height="600" Width="800">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="50"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Label x:Name="Label" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Content="X" Margin="0,0,0,0" Padding="0,0,0,0" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"
           Background="Coral" FontSize="50"/>
</Grid>
```

The problem is that the text in the label does not stay centered vertically when increasing the font size. Like this:

[Font size 50](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2GAnx.png)

It gets pushed down. Is there any way to force the text to stay in the exact middle?

This is with font size 70. It's moving off the screen:

[Font size 70](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rMJua.png)

Comment: You have allocated `Width` and `Height` only with 50 for the cell.  Where you want to centre align?

Comment: GUI related questions like these, will be more approachable if you show us the designflaw with an image, sometimes questions like these can be misinterpreted.

Comment: Yeah the grid cells in the final product should be 50 x 50. And ideally the text should be centered right in the middle to fill that space.

Comment: @wickys Remove all `RowDefinitation` and `ColumnDefinitation` from your `Grid` and specify `Label` with `Width` as 70 and `Height` as 70

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do, can be achieved with a TextBlock instead of a label. They basically gives you the same features with small differences.

```
<TextBlock x:Name="TextBlock" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="X" TextAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
       Background="Coral" FontSize="50"/>
```

**EDIT:**

I don't really like this solutions, however this will give you your result, however it's a bit of a cheat, and it has to be controlled carefully, when you manipulate controls with margins in negative numbers.

```
<Border Margin="0 -5 0 0" Background="Coral">
        <TextBlock Text="X" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" FontSize="50"/>
    </Border>
```

The problem about my first solution is that the text was centered, but the textblock/label is expanded behind the grid, so therefore the offset is visually messed up.

Anyways. Hope this helps you.